# find $\iint\limits_{s} \vec{F}.\vec{n} ds$

Tags: vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I have to find $$\iint\limits_{s} \vec{F}.\vec{n} ds$$ where

$$\vec{F} = 2x^2y \vec{i} - y^2\vec{j} + 4xz^2 \vec{k}$$
and the surface S is the region bounded by the cylinder
$$y^2 + z^2 = 3$$ and $$0 \le x \le 2, y \ge , z \ge 0$$

From Gauss divergence theorem we have,

$$\iint\limits_{s} \vec{F}.\vec{n} ds = \iiint\limits_{V} div \vec{F} dv$$

so, $$div \vec{F} = 4xy - 2y + 8xz$$

How to find the limits of integration for this?

Comment: Change the coordinate system to cylindrical, then the integration limits become natural to determine.

Comment: $y = r \cos\theta, z = r \sin\theta, x = x, 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt3, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. Also note that divergence theorem will give you outward flux through the entire closed surface.